# Change local admin password after provisioning Windows VM in Azure

Tags: powershell, azure, terraform, azure-powershell, terraform-provider-azure

We are using Terraform to provision Windows VMs using a standard Windows 2016 sku from the Marketplace.  I can enter the password interactively at execution time of my Terraform config but it will still write it into the state file which gets stored in an Azure storage account.  I need to change the password after the provision is complete and would prefer to do this programmatically as part of the provisioning process...like maybe thru a PowerShell script executed via a vmextension.

Ideally, would like to be able to have the password changed at the end of the provisioning process and written to a Secret in Key Vault.  The VMs will be joined to AAD Domain Services so we would only need the local admin password in a break glass scenario.

I thought about executing a PowerShell script that would generate the password, change the password on the local account and then use a Managed Service Identity to write it to a Secret in Key Vault but not sure that is going to work in the normal flow of our automation routine.

I know I can use the `Set-AzureRmVMAccessExtension` PowerShell command outside of the provisioning process to change the password and then within the same script write the new value to a Secret in Key Vault but that would be a semi-manual step out of band from our provisioning process.

Any one have any thoughts or other suggestions that have worked?

Comment: Actually, I was incorrect about the password being stored in the State file.  I think what I will do, knowing this...is to generate a random password, store it in Key Vault and programmatically retrieve it at deployment time.

Answer (score 0):

You propose launching a script via vmextension and writing the new password (presumably programmatically-generated) back to Key Vault. That should work fine as long as your MSI service principal has write access to the Key Vault.

I recently submitted a PR to the AzureRM Terraform provider that will allow you assign Key Vault write access via your Terraform template. It's not merged yet, so you can either wait for that to happen, or you can build a custom azurerm provider that incorporates the change. See https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/1052.

Comment: @j-day thanks for the reply...I have been seeing tons of activity with the Terraform AzureRM provider related to adding MSI capability so I think I will just wait till you PR is merged.